# Javascript looping through elements and adding to table

Tags: javascript, html, loops, d3.js

I'm having trouble finding a solution that will help me loop through a bunch of elements and putting the chosen values into a table. I've been able to withdraw some values but the method isn't dynamic.

Here is an example:

```
var Table = {
    "credit": {
        "link": "site link", 
        "logoUrl": "logo url", 
        "message": "message"
    }, 
    "groups": [
        {
            "labels": [
                {
                    "name": "Western Conference", 
                    "type": "conference"
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "Central Division", 
                    "type": "division"
                }
            ], 
            "standings": [
                {
                    "stats": [
                        {
                            "name": "gp", 
                            "value": 20
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "w", 
                            "value": 17
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "l", 
                            "value": 0
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "gf", 
                            "value": 64
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "ga", 
                            "value": 37
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "gd", 
                            "value": 27
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "pts", 
                            "value": 37
                        }
                    ], 
                    "team": {
                        "id": 12345, 
                        "link": "team link", 
                        "name": "team name", 
                        "shortName": "team"
                    }
                },
```

This is the structure of the elements. So far I've used this:

```
document.getElementById("sGamesPlayed").innerHTML=Table.groups[0].standings[0].stats[0].value;
```

to withdraw values. However there are more teams, stats and divisions so I would need some kind of loop to go through the elements and put the into a dynamic table.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by withdraw values. Do you want to filter the elements of the array `stats`? 
Moreover I don't see why you use the d3.js tag as your question does not involve visualization. Do you want a solution using d3 functions?

Comment: An example of the expected output would be handy. You can't use innerHTML to modify parts of a table in IE, though you can use it to write an entire table (e.g. `<table ...>...</table>`, or the contents of a cell (e.g. `cell.innerHTML = '...';`, where `cell` is a reference to a TD or TH element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider you to look at http://underscorejs.org/.

it provides a bunch of utility functions that could help you,
for example, _.each() helps you loop through JSON properties.

for the sample objects you've given (after completing the missing brackets at the end),

```
_.each(Table.groups[0].standings[0].stats, function(stats){
    console.log(stats['name']+","+stats['value'])
})
```

gives me:

```
gp,20
w,17
l,0
gf,64
ga,37
gd,27
pts,37
```

how it works is that you provide the object you want as the first argument and the function that you give as the second argument will be called with each element of the first argument (Assuming it is a list).

I would also urge you to look at underscore templating that you can use to render your table  where i put the console.log :

1. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-cozy-with-underscore-js/
2. http://scriptble.com/2011/01/28/underscore-js-templates/

Comment: They are not "JSON properties" but object properties. JSON is a notation that is used to serialise objects.

Comment: Hello Wingston Sharon and than you for your answer. I was wondering if there is a possibility to add/append/push the data you got out to a backbone collection? Not sure how something like that would look but maybe: teamCollection.push([ name: teamName, gp: gamesPlayed, w: wins, etc... ]);

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is about filtering the values of the array `standings`. In order to do that you can use the [jQuery grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function (if you want to use jQuery).

For example you can write:

```
var arr = $.grep(Table.groups[0].standings[0].stats, function(d){return d.value>25})
```

Which will give

```
arr = [{"name": "gf","value": 64}, {"name": "ga", "value": 37},{"name": "gd", "value": 27},{"name": "pts", "value": 37}]
```

If this is not what you meant, can you please create a jsFiddle with a sample of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the results, you can go over the object using a scheme like:

```
var groups, standings, stats, value;
groups = Table.groups;

// Do stuff with groups

for (var i=0, iLen=groups.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  standings = groups[i].standings;

  // Do stuff with standings

  for (var j=0, jLen=standings.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    stats = standings[j];

    // Do stuff with stats

    for (var k=0, kLen=stats.length; k<kLen; k++) {
      value = stats[k].value;

      // Do stuff with value

    }
  }
}
```

Of course I have no idea what the data is for, what the overall structure is or how you want to present it. But if you have deeply nested data, all you can do is dig into it. You might be able to write a recursive function, but it might also become very difficult to maintain if the data structure is complex.